# How do I authenticating to remote repo inside Github Action using GH CLI?

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-cli

I am having an issue with the following segment of a Github Action/Workflow which is meant to pull the PR list (with some filtering) of a remote, private repo (e.g. not the repo that contains the Action itself).

```
  - run: echo "PR2=$( gh pr list --head "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" --repo github.com/[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO] | tr -s [:space:] ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1 )" >> $GITHUB_ENV
     env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

However, I am getting the following error: `GraphQL: Could not resolve to a Repository with the name '[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO]'. (repository)`

I gather there is some issue with authentication somewhere, since the commands runs perfectly in a terminal after authenticating with gh auth. I'm new to Github as a whole, Actions, and CLI, so any advice as to how to properly authenticate inside an action would be amazing.

Edit: Found a solution/workaround.

Use git ls-remote to get a list of PRs and branches, then link the two using the ID. For future reference:

```
id=$(git ls-remote git@github.com:[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO] | grep "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" | head -c 40)
PR=$(git ls-remote git@github.com:[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO] | grep "${id}.*refs/pull" | cut -b 52- | rev | cut -b 6- | rev)
```

Comment: I  found something talking about this issue on the [Github CLI repo](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/401#issuecomment-588261787). Could you try running the [gh auth login <flags>](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) command before the one you use to list the PR?

Comment: I would love to, but I don't know which token to use. The standard `gh auth login` is an interactive command, so I think I'd need `gh auth login --with-token`, but I don't know exactly how that works.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open feature request for authenticating non-interactively: [Add flags to gh auth login to replace the interactive prompts](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/4506)

You can use [github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script) though:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Find Pull Request
    uses: actions/github-script@v5
    with:
      github-token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_FOR_PRIVATE_REPO }}
      script: |
        const pulls = github.rest.pulls.list({
          owner: '[OWNER]',
          head: '${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}',
          repo: '[REMOTE_REPO]',
        });
```

Note how it passes a separate `github-token`. The default token (`secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`) cannot access your other private repository, so you'll have to [issue another token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and [set that up as a secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets).

If you don't want to use github script, you could also use plain curl with the newly issued token. Here's the doc on the REST API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests and how to use the token: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I will keep those tools in mind going forward. I managed to hack a solution using `git ls-remote` to get a list of PRs and branches, then linked the two using the ID. For future reference:

`id=$(git ls-remote git@github.com:[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO] | grep "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" | head -c 40)`

`PR=$(git ls-remote git@github.com:[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO] | grep "${id}.*refs/pull" | cut -b 52- | rev | cut -b 6- | rev)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specifically authenticate using `gh auth`, but you should be using a generated PAT which has access to the private repo in this case.

1. For example, generate a PAT which can access your private repo, steps: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token
2. Add the PAT as a secret to the repo where you have your workflow, say *PRIVATE_REPO_PAT* , steps: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository

Then, you can use that in your workflow like:

```
- run: echo "PR2=$( gh pr list --head "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" --repo github.com/[OWNER]/[REMOTE_REPO] | tr -s [:space:] ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1 )" >> $GITHUB_ENV
     env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_REPO_PAT }}
```

Note that, if you do want to use gh auth 'non-interactively', say in a shell script, you could always do it using :

```
echo "$GH_CONFIG_TOKEN" | gh auth login --with-token
```

where GH_CONFIG_TOKEN is either the default GITHUB_TOKEN or a generated PAT.

For use in Github Actions, this auth is implicit when you pass in the correct *GITHUB_TOKEN* in the env variables.